# Is it possible to integrate third party frameworks withing a JHipster project?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I tried to install the `Clarity Design System` (https://vmware.github.io/clarity/) into my created `JHipster` project following the installation guide (https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started). Means, after executing the `npm install`s, I added the styles and scripts to the `.angular-cli.json` and adding the import declaration to the `app.module.ts`. Unfortunately, this did not work:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/modal/modal.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/modal'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/modal/modal.js 7:0-81
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/modal/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/stack-view/stack-block.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/data/stack-view'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/stack-view/stack-block.js 7:0-81
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/stack-view/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/tree-view/tree-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/data/tree-view'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/tree-view/tree-node.js 17:0-81
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/data/tree-view/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/collapse/collapse.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/collapse'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/collapse/collapse.js 6:0-72
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/collapse/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade/fade.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade/fade.js 6:0-65
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade-slide/fade-slide.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade-slide'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade-slide/fade-slide.js 6:0-65
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/fade-slide/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/slide/slide.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/Users/ndinatale/src/llqa-3-prototype/node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/slide'
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/slide/slide.js 6:0-65
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/utils/animations/slide/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/clarity-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
```

How can I integrate this (and other) frameworks into a JHipster project?

Comment: Editing .angular-cli.json cannot help because Jhipster does not use it for its build: it has its own webpack configuration. have you read the README.md file in your project?

Comment: After consulting the README.md stating to put the styles in the `vendor.css` and the scripts in the `vendor.ts`, I did that. But still the same error...

Comment: can you update your question with the angular-cli.json

Answer (score 1):

1. insert follow lines to package.json to "dependencies" section
    
    `...,
    "dependencies": {
      ...
      "clarity-icons": "0.10.7",
      "clarity-ui": "0.10.7",
      "clarity-angular": "0.10.7",
      "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.0.4",
      "mutationobserver-shim": "0.3.2",
      "@angular/animations": "4.4.4"
     }`
2. install added packages: 
    
    `npm install`
3. add follow lines into vendor.ts file:

   `import 'mutationobserver-shim';
    import '@webcomponents/custom-elements';
    import 'clarity-icons';
    import 'clarity-icons/shapes/social-shapes';
    import 'clarity-icons/shapes/technology-shapes';`
4. include ClarityModule in app.module.ts
5. Run `yarn run webpack:build`
6. Run `yarn start` and test it out!
7. you need change other parts... nav bar, routes and etc...